# Undefined error when trying to read and change value from useState using keydown on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, html5-canvas, keydown

I have been trying to create a little animation on canvas using React.js but having trouble interacting my Keydown function with my useState, for some reason, it wouldn't define my useState value, and therefore I couldn't change the value when I press the key. Here is my code:

```
  const Canvas = () => {
  const { innerWidth: innerwidth, innerHeight: innerheight } = window;
  const contextRef= useRef()
  const [placement, setPlacement] = useState({position: {x:100,y:100}, width:30,height:30, velocity: {x:0, y:0}})
  const gravity = 4.5

  const draw = (context) => {
    context.fillStyle = 'red'
    context.fillRect(placement.position.x, placement.position.y, placement.width, placement.height);
  }; 

  const update = (context, canvas) => {
    draw(context)
    setPlacement(placement.position.y += placement.velocity.y)
    if(placement.position.y+placement.height+placement.velocity.y <= canvas.height){
      setPlacement(placement.velocity.y += gravity)
    }else{
      setPlacement(placement.velocity.y = 0)
    }
  }

  const animate = (context, width, height, canvas ) => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => { animate(context, width, height, canvas ) })
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height) 
    update(context, canvas)
  } 

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = contextRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width= innerwidth
    canvas.height= innerheight
    animate(context, canvas.width, canvas.height, canvas)
    
  }, []);


const handleKeydown = (e) => {
  switch(e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      console.log("left")
      return "left";
    case 39:
      return "right";
    case 32:
      return setPlacement(placement.position.y -= 20);
       
    default:
      console.log("keyCode is " + e.keyCode)
      console.log(placement.velocity)
      return 'default';
    }    
  }


  return (
    <canvas ref={contextRef} tabIndex={-1} onKeyDown={ (e)=>{handleKeydown(e)}} />
  );
};
```

As you can see I have been trying to console.log my placement in my function, but I am getting either a "0" or undefined. Here is the error I get when I hit my spacebar:

[image]

What can I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the format of the state value completely from what it is initially set to.

Your default is

```
useState({position: {x:100,y:100}, width:30,height:30, velocity: {x:0, y:0}})
```

However you then go on to wipe this out with a single value

```
setPlacement(placement.velocity.y += gravity)
```

The object is now gone completely, and you are storing one integer.

This also makes no sense as you are doing an assignment to `placement.velocity.y` inside the actual argument. I think you thought this would granularly change this one property but that's not how it works. What you need to do is pass the whole object, with the one value you want to change altered. You can do this by merging the old and the new state.

```
// before

setPlacement(placement.position.y += placement.velocity.y)

// after

setPlacement(prevPlacement => ({ ...prevPlacement, position: { ...prevPlacement.position, y: prevPlacement.position.y + prevPlacement.velocity.y } }))
```

```
// before

setPlacement(placement.velocity.y += gravity)

// after

setPlacement(prevPlacement => ({ ...prevPlacement, velocity: { ...prevPlacement.velocity, y: prevPlacement.velocity.y + gravity } }))
```

```
// before

setPlacement(placement.velocity.y = 0)

// after

setPlacement(prevPlacement => ({ ...prevPlacement, velocity: { ...prevPlacement.velocity, y: 0 } }))
```

```
// before

setPlacement(placement.position.y -= 20);

// after

setPlacement(prevPlacement => ({ ...prevPlacement, position: { ...prevPlacement.position, y: placement.position.y - 20 } }))
```

As an aside, with deep structures, this is obviously messier. You might consider switching to multiple state items -- but it depends on what changes together (that's optimal). Probably it would be 3 state items, `position`, `velocity` and `dimensions`. That avoids very-deep state updates.

Or you can use some library like https://github.com/immerjs/immer which makes mutating deep state in an immutable way much easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't realize that silly mistake, its a good idea to switch it into multiple state items i am going to do that now!

Comment: I have tried your methods and also separated them into different state items but it doesn't seem updating my state

Comment: @tomtom If you post a new question with the modified broken code, happy to help. Keep in mind one common thing people new to react do is log immediately after the settings of state. That always returns the old value, because in react, state is flushed later.